# Devise for Twitter, Cookie Overflow error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise

I am trying to integrate twitter into devise using this [guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview). I basically take all occurence of facebook and substitue it with twitter. However, when I sign in with twitter, I am getting the following error:

```
ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow (ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieOverflow):
```

at the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=something&oauth_verifier=blah
```

Is there any nice way to get around fixing this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The problem is with `session["devise.facebook_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]`. Twitter's response contains an `extra` section that is very large and does not fit in the session. One option is to store `env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")` in the session instead.

Comment: To figure out I didn't need the "extra" section, I used `raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml`

Answer (score 7):

You can turn on ActiveRecord store for session.
Look in config/initializers/session_store.rb

comment out the line about using :cookie_store

uncomment the lines at the bottom about using :active_record_store

```
# Use the database for sessions instead of the cookie-based default,
# which shouldn't be used to store highly confidential information
# (create the session table with "rails generate session_migration")
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store
```

Create migration before rails `rails g session_migration` and migrate it.

Comment: are there ever any disadvantageous side effects?

Comment: I believe you only should use active record store if your session data is bigger than 4K, it's a bit slower than storing it in the cookie.

Comment: Some out of the box rails open source cms's fail to work with this change, btw...