# Skip email validation for omniauth-twitter on devise 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm using devise 2.0 and gem [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter)

The problem is that twitter does not send an email in response, so the model user of my application validates that there is an email and I get the following error in the callback:

```
Email can't be blank
```

I have this in my **user.rb** model:

```
#config omniauth twitter
def self.find_for_twitter_oauth(access_token, signed_in_resource = nil)
    data = access_token.extra.raw_info
    if user = User.where(:username => data.screen_name).first
        user
    else
        User.create!(:username => data.screen_name, :password => Devise.friendly_token)
    end
end
```

and I have this in my **omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
  def twitter
    @user = User.find_for_twitter_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Twitter"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117200/devise-for-twitter-cookie-overflow-error
      session["devise.twitter_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
   end
```

I want force to user to give a email address for send newsletter, advertirser...etc

**How can I fix this problem?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

Add this to your User model:

```
def email_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end
```

You can use an equivalent method for the password:

```
def password_required?
  super && provider.blank?
end
```

This should override the field requirements when using Omniauth providers.

Comment: Same issue here, have imlpemented your code to my user.rb but i'm getting the following error: undefined local variable or method `provider' for #<User:0x007ffdfc41d730>. the provider method isn't defined anywhere in the user.rb?

Comment: @TonyP Do you have a `provider` attribute on your User model?

Comment: Could you add a little more explanation what it does? If there are hand written validation rules in user.rb for password and email, does it work either? For me not :(

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem, Twitter doesn't give you the email via oauth, you have to think in another way to obtain the email. The only solution that I figured out, is override the callback and use the twitter data to autocomplete a form and give the user the chance to complete his mail by himself and then sign up and save the user in the database.

Look the following question:

[Is there a way to get an user's email ID after verifying his/her Twitter identity using OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599621/is-there-a-way-to-get-an-users-email-id-after-verifying-her-twitter-identity-us)

Answer (score 2):

A solution is explained thoroughly here:
http://asciicasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2

And on GitHub:
https://github.com/fertapric/rails3-mongoid-devise-omniauth/wiki/How-To:-Retrieve-email-information-(middle-step)-from-providers-like-Twitter-or-LinkedIn

For some reason, this question shows up higher in Google's ranks than these links, so I thought I'd add them to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the presence validation of the email field.
Follow [this post](http://jessewolgamott.com/blog/2011/12/08/the-one-where-devise-validations-are-customized/) and see if that works.
Sorry for the late response, hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you jacobaweiss, but I need get a email from user. I can not save in my database a user without his email :(. Perhaps I need create a redirect and show a form and user must write the email for create his account. How can I do it? Thank you

Comment: I think you need to force the user to some form to fill the information, but I'm searching how to do that either :/