# Rails+Devise+OmniAuth: How to skip email validation for Twitter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, twitter, devise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Skip email validation for omniauth-twitter on devise 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226203/skip-email-validation-for-omniauth-twitter-on-devise-2-0)

I am using this validation rules for email:

```
  validates :email,
            :presence => true, 
            :format => { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
            :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false }

  before_save do |user| 
        user.email = email.downcase#
        user.slug  = user.username.parameterize
  end
```

And I tried to add:

```
  def email_required?
    super && provider.blank?
  end
```

For skipping email validation, if a visitor want to sign up through Twitter, but I am still getting error here, it looks that the `email_required?` doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`email_required` DOES work if you want to skip devise's validation, see: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/c179cef365f7188c91cbbc3db924a9f1f9563c3c/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L29
But if you want to skip your own email validation you can use something like this:

```
validates :email,
          :presence => true, 
          :format => { :with => VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, 
          :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false },
          :if => 'provider.blank?'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply nash. When I try this, there is still one issue - I am getting the error `undefined method 'downcase' for nil:NilClass` on the first line in the `before_save` block. How can I handle this issue? In the database scheme is set up that email cannot be blank.

Comment: you can just checking if there is an email in `before_save`: `user.email = email.downcase if email`

Comment: But in that case I get the error message `PG::Error: ERROR:  null value in column "email" violates not-null constraint`